# Optimize Union request

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, union

I work with SQL.
I have two tables

Table 1:
ID, thing_name, thing_code, thing_localisation

Table 2:
ID, thing_id, thing_value_1, thing_value_2, eval_year, eval_month, T1_ID

Table 1 contains some things. A thing have a name, a code and a localisation. Table 2 contains entries corresponding of differents evaluations of things. Evaluations that have been done monthly.
We don't evaluate every thing every month, so we have some things which are not evaluated every month

WHAT I WANT TO DO?

I want to:

1)
I want to have the sum of evaluations done for every thing related to a specific local called "LOCAL_0" before the beginning of a specific year (Year y). 
The SQL query corresponding look likes this:

```
SELECT T.thing_code, SUM(E.thing_eval_1), SUM(E.thing_eval_2)
FROM table1 T, table2 E
WHERE T.ID = E.T1_ID AND T.thing_localisation = "LOCAL_0" AND E.eval_year < y
```

2)   I want to have the sum of evaluations of things (related to LOCAL_0) done from the beginning of year y to the end of the month m in year y. The SQL query for this looks like :

```
SELECT T.thing_code, SUM(E.thing_eval_1), SUM(E.thing_eval_2)
FROM table1 T, table2 E
WHERE T.ID = E.T1_ID AND T.thing_localisation = "LOCAL_0"
AND E.eval_year = y and E.eval_month <= m
```

The result of the first query looks like

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| thing_code    SUM_EVAL_1_BEFORE    SUM_EVAL 2_BEFORE |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 111           1                    2                 |
| 112           3                    4                 |
| 113           5                    6                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The result of the second query looks like

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| thing_code    SUM_EVAL_1_NOW   SUM_EVAL_2_NOW |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 110           0.5              0.3            |
| 111           0.1              0.1            |
| 112           1                0.9            |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

3)   I want finally build a request that give me this result

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| thing_code EVAL_1_BEF EVAL_2_BEF EVAL_1_NOW EVAL_2_NOW EVAL_1_NOW E2_NOW |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 110        0          0          0.5        0.3        0.5        0.3    |
| 111        1          2          0.1        0.1        1.1        2.1    |
| 112        3          4          1          0.9        4          4.9    |
| 113        5          6          0          0          5          6      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To do this, i searched and i found a request that works well but i takes too long go give the result (cause really the database is very big, have many entries, millions rows)

```
SELECT UN.code,
       UN.Eval1_BEF,
       UN.Eval2_BEF,
       UN.Eval1_NOW,
       UN.Eval2_NOW,
       (UN.Eval1_BEF + UN.Eval1_NOW) AS Eval1_AFTER,
       (UN.Eval2_BEF + UN.Eval2_NOW) AS Eval2_AFTER

FROM
(
SELECT R1.thing_code AS code, R1.Eval1 AS Eval1_BEF, R1.Eval2 AS Eval2_BEF, R2.Eval1 AS Eval1_NOW, R2.Eval2 AS Eval2_NOW
FROM Result_Request_1 R1 LEFT JOIN Result_Request_2 R2 ON R1.thing_code = R2.thing code

UNION

SELECT R2.thing_code AS code, R1.Eval1 AS Eval1_BEF, R1.Eval2 AS Eval2_BEF, R2.Eval1 AS Eval1_NOW, R2.Eval2 AS Eval2_NOW
FROM Result_Request_1 R1 RIGHT JOIN Result_Request_2 R2 ON R1.thing_code = R2.thing code

) UN

ORDER BY UN.code;
```

I want to optimize this request because it takes too long. Can anyone help me? Sorry for my poor english...

Comment: no thing_code values are only in table_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    T.thing_code,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.eval_year < y THEN E.thing_eval_1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_EVAL_1_BEFORE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.eval_year < y THEN E.thing_eval_2 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_EVAL_2_BEFORE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.eval_year = y and E.eval_month <= m
             THEN E.thing_eval_1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_EVAL_1_NOW,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.eval_year = y and E.eval_month <= m
             THEN E.thing_eval_2 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_EVAL_2_NOW
FROM table1 T
INNER JOIN table2 E
    ON T.ID = E.T1_ID
WHERE
    T.thing_localisation = 'LOCAL_0'
GROUP BY
    T.thing_code;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try and i give you a feedback

Comment: Thank you very much Tim Biegeleisen. I understood your solution, it was very simple.